# Foreign key shows nulls (ssms)

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, foreign-keys

I am trying to do a very simple task - to connect two tables with a foreign key. However, after successful creating of the key, the column in the main table is full of NULL values.

I tried to create the relationship both with a script and using 'Design table' option.

So, I have two tables - Swimmer (Has 100000 rows)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Swimmer](
[SwimmerID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
[FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[LastName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[PassportNumber] [nvarchar](20) ,
[BirthDate] [date] NOT NULL,
[Gender] [nvarchar](5) ,
[Rank] [nvarchar](10) ,
[CoachID] [int]  )
```

And Coach (has 10000 rows):

```
    [CoachID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [PassportNumber] [nvarchar](20) )
```

I want to connect them by CoachID, so the column CoachID in Swimmer becomes a foreign key that references the column CoachID in Coach, however when I do, the column CoachID in Swimmer just shows NULL in every row.
My next task will be to create a one-to-many relationship (since one coach can instruct multiple swimmers), but for now I just want to figure out why the connection is not working

Comment: How do you add the foreign key?

Comment: Do you mean your Swimmer table has data in the CoachID column, which disappears when you add the foreign key?!?

Comment: Please share the code you used when you tried to add the foreign key. Basically, you must populate both tables and then go back and update the coachId in the swimmer table based on *some logic* or mapping... how do you know which swimmer gets which coach? this is where your problem is.

Comment: What foreign key? There isn't one defined. And a foreign key column only has a non-`NULL` value in it if when you `INSERT` or `UPDATE` the row said column has a value; SQL Server doesn't "magically" know what value it should be when you define it.

Comment: I believe that just creating the foreign key relationship between the two tables doesn't not automatically populate the values in your `Swimmer` table. After the relationship is created you then need to go and update the `Swimmer.CoachId` values to contain id values that are in the `Coach` table.

Comment: sorry, the above comment should be ".... does not automatically..."